# AngularJS ng-if does not work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ng-if, angularjs-ng-show

In the controller, I have this

```
var onComplete = function(response)
{
        $scope.reportList = response.data;      
        $log.info($scope.reportList);                       
};
```

In the HTML, reportList is a JSON like this `{packageType=1, salary=12900 }`.
`ReportList` is not an array `{{ reportList.packageTypeId }}  return 1`

The issue is with `ng-if` div

```
<div class="exceptionProcedure" ng-if=" reportList.packageType == 1"> 

<a> display package 1 </a>
```

when I tried this, it still does not work

```
<div class="exceptionProcedure" ng-if=" {{reportList.packageType}} == 1">

 <a> display package 1 </a>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`

Comment: The later one i.e. `ng-if=" {{reportList.packageType}} == 1"` is anyways wrong? Can you please print the type of `packageType` value? Something like: `console.log(typeof $scope.reportList.packageType);`

Comment: I got it fixed. Thanks. Missing the closing tag :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `reportList.packageType` on the initial page load so that it links between your controller and view:

```
$scope.reportList = {}
var onComplete = function(response) {
    $scope.reportList = response.data;
    $log.info($scope.reportList);
};
```

This way, you'll only have one version that is shared between controller and view.  The way you're doing it now creates two separate versions.